# Как сделать объект со свойствами строкой?

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь написать функцию [`rle`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9).
Например: есть строка `АААВВCKKK` возвращать должна `3А2B1C3K`.

Мой код:

```
function ll (str) {
    var newStr = '';
    var obj = {};
    var sum;
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
       if( obj[str[i]] ){ 
            obj[str[i]]++;
       }
       else{
            obj[str[i]] = 1;
       }
    }
    for (var i in obj){
        alert(i + obj[i]);
    } 
}
console.log(ll('AABBBBCCCCllkkk'));
```

Не получается вывести строку, при соединении выводится только `2А`, хотя по алерту все свойства объекта.
Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: сконкатинируй в строку в цикле (вместо alert) и сделай в конце функции `return` этой строки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
String.prototype.ll = function(){
  return this.match(/(.)\1+/ig).reduce((acc, part) => acc += `${part.length}${part[0]}`, '');
}

console.info('AABBBBCCCCllkkk'.ll());
```

Comment: @Ирина, всегда пожалуйста. Однако спасибо тут принято выражать плюсами и, если помогло, принятием ответа (зелёная галочка слева от ответа).

Comment: кроме галочки, не могу больше ничего сделать, рейтинг видимо не позволяет

Comment: @Ирина, да, необходимо 15 репутации, ничего страшного, зато я Вам плюсанул :)

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: вместо match/reduce надо было replace

Comment: @Grundy, да, вполне может быть.

Answer (score 1):

Вы ничего не возвращаете из функции. Попробуйте так

```js
function ll (str) {
  var newStr = '';
  var obj = {};
  var sum;
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    if( obj[str[i]] ){ 
      obj[str[i]]++;
    }
    else{
      obj[str[i]] = 1;
    }
  }
  s = "";
  for (var i in obj){
    s += (i + obj[i]);
  } 
  return s;
}

console.log(ll('AABBBBCCCCllkkk'));
```